# Why the use of "going to" in that case

Tags: will-vs-going-to, future-tense

John wanted to have his wife  murdered. He looked for someone and found a person who could do it, his name was Paul. John explained how Paul would have to do it, and then answered a question asked by Paul. His answer was "she will be dead, she **is not going to** speak"

This story is based on a Hitchcok's film "Dial M for murder".

My question is  why did John use the "going to" form. Is it because it is an **evidence**  (as "look there are some clouds, it is going to rain") or an **intention** but when you are dead you have no intention  or because it has been **planned before**.

Could "going to"  be replaced by "will"?

Answer (score 1):

"Going to [verb]" is simply another construction for future action. It means the same thing as "will [verb]", but is slightly less formal.

"It will rain" and "it is going to rain" mean the same thing.

"She is not going to speak" and "she will not speak" mean the same thing.

The "going to [verb]" construction comes from actually being in the process of moving (i.e. going) somewhere to perform an action, but now it can be used for any future action.

Answer (score -1):

We use "Going to" if we planned something. But If we don't planned anything, we use "will".

Here's example with "going to" sentences.

> “It’s going to rain tomorrow”
>
> "They are going to fight"
>
> “I am going to go to work early”

Here's "will" one.

> "I’ll do it next week"

- He just made a decision

> “I’ll pay for the food”

- He just made a decision again, while they eating.

The answer of your question is evidence.

Hope I could help.

Comment: ok that is what I thought but was not sure because the murdered had also planned before

Comment: If he wanted to kill someone, he need a plan :). If you think my answer was helpful, you can verify my answer so other can see it and learn.

Comment: so my answer of my question is not because it is an evidence but i because it has been planned before  or may be both of them, I  will approuve your answer as soon as you have answered to my comment .

Comment: If you want to kill someone, do you plan or not?

Comment: of course but the reason why John answered using going to is not evidence but the planificatiion he did  before    if they were no plan it would not use the going to form . Am I right

Comment: I do not understand the relationship you two are drawing between "planning" and "going to". Is this a rule that has been taught to you?

Comment: yes going to future is for something planned before as a killing

Comment: @user5577 I am a native speaker with a formal education, and I have never heard of this rule. They are really used more or less interchangeably.

Comment: I am native speaker with a formal education too and we always learned "going to" used in plan sentences.